# Mac OS - Video Capturing

Tags: macos, mac, video, video-capture

What's the good software to capture anything that is going on at my screen to a video file that I can later on upload to let's say YouTube? I'm using Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QuickTimeX](http://www.apple.com/macosx/technology/#quicktimex) comes with OS X and can do this for you.

Some other good 3rd party tools:

- [Camtasia for Mac](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasiamac/)
- [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm)
- [Capture Me](http://www.chimoosoft.com/products/captureme/)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I think [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) is the best of the bunch for video capturing.</strike>

**Scratch that!** Snapz Pro X is *expensive* and *slow* and rather *outdated* at this point. I've started using [Screeny](http://www.screenyapp.com/) and love it. Integrates with [CloudApp](http://www.cloudapp.com/) for uploading if you like, has a slick easy to use UI, and most importantly doesn't cripple my machine when recording a screen cast<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1: This could also be the 12GB of ram and quad-core processor, but I like to think it's just a better written app.</sup>

Comment: Josh that's $70. Any justification of "is the best?" Although the others seem to be $99, s...

Comment: @Yar: I'm going to update this 2009 answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

Open QuickTime / File / New screen recorder.

See this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5XYYP8nBNg#t=02m10s)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Quicktime X can record both sound and video. Another free option is [Copernicus](http://www.danicsoft.com/projects/copernicus/). I used that successfully under Leopard. I've not tried it with 10.6 but see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another for consideration is iShowU. It's not as heavily marketed, but it's updated fairly frequently and it's got a much more Mac-like interface than Snapz. It's really powerful without being difficult to use, too.